# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00200074 ; happens when returning from function

Tags: visual-c++, character-encoding, access-violation

I'm currently developing a program that reads strings from a text file in 8-bit ASCII mode, and I make a function to assign that string into a wchar_t*

Here I'm using atlconv.h and USES_CONVERSION macro to convert the string into wstring. So here is the code:

```
void CSampleProvider::getCopy(CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_DESCRIPTOR *a, const string s) {
    USES_CONVERSION;
    wstring temp(A2W (s.c_str ()));
    a->pszLabel = new WCHAR(temp.length()+1);
    if (!a->pszLabel)
        return;
    wcscpy_s(a->pszLabel, temp.size()+1, (LPWSTR)temp.c_str());
    ::MessageBox(NULL,s.c_str(),"getCopy",0);
    return;
}
```

I used a debugger to watch line by line. It works well (i.e. the content of a->pszLabel is as I expected, the same as the content of s) until it reaches return. As it returned, an error popped up:

```
First-chance exception at 0x770f3067 in CPTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00200074.
Unhandled exception at 0x770f3067 in CPTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00200074.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Please tell me. Your answers are highly appreciated :)

Thanks,
Reinardus

EDIT: Oh yeah, the type CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_DESCRIPTOR is a struct, and one of its member is pszLabel, which is a wchar_t*

Comment: Does your string have a `t ` in it by any chance? Does the "reading location" seem to depend on the contents of `s`?

Comment: Yeah, actually I made mistake in constructing new WCHAR there. Please see the answer, it solves my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a->pszLabel = new WCHAR(temp.length()+1);` returns a pointer to a new `WCHAR` whose value is the length of your string plus one. You meant `a->pszLabel = new WCHAR[temp.length()+1];` which returns a pointer to a new array of `WCHAR` with the number of elements being the length of your string plus one.

Answer (score 0):

These things are hard to debug without more complete information, but given that you see the error when returning from the function, my guess would be that a buffer overflow overwrites the return address, causing the code to jump to some arbitrary, non-rx memory location.